# What is the proper syntax for child selectors with Sass?

Tags: css, syntax, sass

I am converting my current css file to scss. I should mention this is my first time attempting to use Sass, and things are going very well so far. I have a question when it comes to child selectors with Sass. I have the following code:

```
.ticker-basic.holiday2013 {
    background-color:#e4242b !important;
    color:#ffffff;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-size:14px;
    font-family: 'HelveticaNeueW01-85Heav', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    text-transform: lowercase;

    p  {
        text-transform: capitalize;
    }

    p > a {
        color:#ffffff;
        text-decoration: underline;
        font-weight:normal;
        font-size:10px;
    }
}
```

Am I able to nest the child a tag in the above p tag? Such as this:

```
    p  {
        text-transform: capitalize;

        > a {
            color:#ffffff;
            text-decoration: underline;
            font-weight:normal;
            font-size:10px;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try it and find out?  I don't understand what the problem here is.

Comment: It happens to be something I'm not able to test at the moment. It is served dynamically, and we are unable to try it and see. I was hoping to have it converted with proper syntax before I have the ability to test.

Comment: [We are not human compilers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289336/is-it-okay-to-downvote-questions-asking-if-some-code-could-work-but-not-actually), test before asking.

Comment: @cimmanon as I said, I am unable to test this specific code as the html affected is served dynamically. I figured it was a simple yes or no question to someone with experience with Sass, and I could not find a question related that answered. I have spent my fair share of time assisting others in need, and have received great support in matters such as this in the past. Sorry if I offended anyone....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
p {
  > a {
  ...
  }
}
```

would apply only on the direct sibling anchors of paragraph element while

```
p {
  a {
  ...
  }
}
```

would apply to all the anchors inside the paragraph element. But that doesn't have any behavioral changes as css or sass. You are going in the right direction it seems. The is no better way to learn than to play around and learn for yourself.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation. I should have mentioned I am unable to test locally at the moment. I appreciate your input!